# About listener.cpp tutorial. disobey cpp grammar?

Tags: ros, c++, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 #include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
    
      ros::NodeHandle n;
    
      ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, chatterCallback);
    
      ros::spin(); 
    
      return 0;
    }
```

there is no actual parameter passing to chatterCallback function?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255154/about-listener.cpp-tutorial.-disobey-cpp-grammar?/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`chatterCallback` is used a function pointer in this context, so the function isn't being called by `advertise()`. Instead, the address of the function is stored and used later to call that function every time a new message arrives.

Here's a [wikipedia article about function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) and another article specifically about [using function pointers in C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) if you want to learn more about the details.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-20**:
Thanks! I found I was stupid and forgot the function pointers...